# JetBrains Rider Environment Variable not being set launchsettings

Tags: asp.net-core, jetbrains-rider

I am using JetBrains Rider and attempting to set environment variables for an integration test project I have. In my `launchsettings.json` I have it set but in code when I use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOSDB_KEY") it returns null.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "profiles": {
        "FooBar.IntegrationTests": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "COSMOSDB_KEY": "SUPERMAN",
                "foo": "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the test I am selecting `FooBar.IntegrationTests` under the profile. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you try to restart will it be solved?You can try to refer to the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28367).

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me. Sharing in case found helpful for other devs

my *.http directory structure

```
- Requests
    - Breakfast
        - CreateBreakfast.http
```

1. I right clicked on `Requests` folder
2. Click "Tools -> Start Index"

After that, I was able to see my environment:
[image]